# How to track valid from and valid to from history table

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tracking, history

I have a table users, I want to track their valid from and valid to dates for each profile user worked on and last valid to as null for the existing profile.

```
select id,email,ROLE,PROFILE,
    min_last_modified_date as valid_from, lead(min_last_modified_date) over (partition by 
    id order by min_last_modified_date) as valid_to 
    from
    (
      select id,email,ROLE,PROFILE,
      min(last_modified_date) as min_last_modified_date,
      max(last_modified_date) as max_last_modified_date
      from users_table 
      group by 1,2,3,4 
    )
```

[sample table]

| ID | ROLE | EMPLOYEE_NUMBER | PROFILE | LAST_MODIFIED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Managers | U001 | General Manager | 2020-03-24 0:10:35 |
| 1 | Managers | U001 | General Manager | 2020-04-13 13:23:22 |
| 1 | Managers | U001 | General Manager | 2020-04-14 23:39:53 |
| 1 | Managers | U001 | General Manager | 2020-05-04 17:06:57 |
| 1 | Managers | U001 | General Manager | 2020-06-30 0:21:23 |
| 1 | Managers | U001 | National Acquisition Lead | 2020-06-30 21:13:53 |
| 1 | Puebla Supervisor | U001 | General Manager | 2020-11-24 11:54:33 |
| 1 | Managers | U001 | General Manager | 2020-12-03 0:32:42 |
| 1 | Managers | U001 | General Manager | 2022-02-23 1:52:10 |
| 1 | Managers | U001 | General Manager | 2022-04-29 19:29:49 |

[sample table2]

| ID | EMAIL | ROLE | PROFILE | LAST_MODIFIED_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | bcd | Puebla Supervisor | Vendor Team | 2020-07-25 21:25:43 |
| 2 | bcd | PueblaSupervisor | Vendor Team | 2020-07-29 19:18:38 |
| 2 | bcd | PueblaSupervisor | Vendor Team | 2020-12-27 19:25:50 |
| 2 | bcd | Puebla Supervisor | Vendor Team | 2021-01-03 18:22:38 |
| 2 | bcd | BelfastSupervisor | Vendor Team | 2021-01-10 0:54:47 |
| 2 | bcd | Belfast Supervisor | Vendor Team | 2021-01-10 18:43:14 |
| 2 | bcd | Belfast Supervisor | Vendor Team | 2021-02-14 22:39:38 |
| 2 | bcd | Belfast Supervisor | Vendor Team | 2021-02-22 17:43:56 |
| 2 | bcd | Alorica RTA | Vendor Team | 2021-03-02 5:05:24 |
| 2 | bcd | Alorica RTA | Vendor Team | 2021-03-11 18:43:39 |
| 2 | bcd | Alorica RTA | Vendor Team | 2021-09-06 2:02:24 |
| 2 | bcd | Alorica RTA | Vendor Team | 2021-09-20 3:05:10 |

[getting output like this for sample table 1]

| ID | EMAIL | ROLE | PROFILE | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | Outside Sales Managers | General Manager | 2020-03-24 0:10:35 | 2021-02-25 22:20:11 |
| 1 | abc | Outside Sales Managers | National Acquisition Lead | 2021-02-25 22:20:11 | Null |

[getting output like this for sample table 2]

| ID | EMAIL | ROLE | PROFILE | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | bcd | Puebla Supervisor | Vendor Team | 2020-03-24 0:10:35 | NULL |
| 2 | bcd | Belfast Supervisor | Vendor Team | 2020-03-24 0:10:35 | NULL |
| 2 | bcd | Alorica RTA | Vendor Team | 2020-03-24 0:10:35 | NULL |

[Expected output for sample table 1]

| ID | EMAIL | ROLE | PROFILE | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | Outside Sales Managers | General Manager | 2020-03-24 0:10:35 | 2021-02-25 22:20:11 |
| 1 | abc | Outside Sales Managers | National Acquisition Lead | 2021-02-25 | 22:20:11 2021-03-31 22:39:50 |
| 1 | abc | Outside Sales Managers | General Manager | 2021-03-31 22:39:50 | NULL |

[Expected output for sample table 2]

| ID | EMAIL | ROLE | PROFILE | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | bcd | Puebla Supervisor | Vendor Team | 2020-03-24 0:10:35 | 2021-01-03 18:22:38 |
| 2 | bcd | Belfast Supervisor | Vendor Team | 2021-01-03 18:22:38 | 2021-02-22 17:43:56 |
| 2 | bcd | Alorica RTA | Vendor Team | 2021-02-22 17:43:56 | NULL |

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches can be to identify concurrent rows with same profile into a same bucket(i.e. group).

- First distinguish each row based on the next profile and prev profile it encounters.
- If the previous or next profile is null(i.e. first or last entry in the table) , default it to the current profile.
- Then your window function can do the proper partitions.

  select 
  distinct 
  ID  
  , email 
  , role 
  , profile 
  , min(last_modified_date) over (partition by ID, email, role, adjacent_role_ind order by last_modified_date) as valid_from 
  , lead(last_modified_date,1,null) over (partition by ID, email, role, adjacent_role_ind order by last_modified_date) as valid_to 
  from 
  (
  select 
  ID 
  , email 
  , role 
  , profile 
  , last_modified_date 
  , sum(prev_profile) over ( order by last_modified_date) as adjacent_role_ind 
  from 
  ( 
  select 
  ID 
  , email 
  , role 
  , profile 
  , last_modified_date 
  , case 
  when lag(profile, 1, 0) over (order by last_modified_date) != profile 
  then 1 
  else 0 
  end as prev_profile 
  from users 
  ) 
  ;

You can format the above query into a CTE for a clear code block and optimal execution.

Comment: Hi, Can you please check sample table2 , getting output 2 and expected output 2, If role differs, getting different output

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query adapted from the logic laid out in @shubh_8175's answer. I tried to edit their answer because the logic is sound and only small changes needed to be made to get the correct output but the queue is full

1. Detect profile changes over time per id
2. Group profile changes within id
3. Get the valid dates within those profile groups
4. Aggregate to remove the changes within profile groups

```
with cte as (
    select
        [id]
        ,[email]
        ,[role]
        ,[profile]
        ,[last_modified_date]
        ,case when lag([profile]) over (order by [last_modified_date]) = [profile] then 0 else 1 end as [new_profile]
    from users_table 
),

profile_grouping as (
    select
        [id]
        ,[email]
        ,[role]
        ,[profile]
        ,[last_modified_date]
        ,sum([new_profile]) over ( order by [last_modified_date]) as [profile_n]
    from cte 
),

valid_dates as (
    select
        [id]
        ,[email]
        ,[role]
        ,[profile]
        ,[last_modified_date]
        ,[profile_n]
        ,min(last_modified_date) over (partition by [id], [profile_n] order by [last_modified_date]) as [valid_from]
        ,lead(last_modified_date) over (partition by [id] order by [profile_n]) as [valid_to]
    from profile_grouping
)

select
     [id]
    ,[email]
    ,[role]
    ,[profile]
    ,[profile_n]
    ,min([valid_from]) [valid_from]
    ,case when [profile_n] = max([profile_n]) over ( partition by [id] ) then null else max([valid_to]) end [valid_to]
from valid_dates
group by 
     [id]
    ,[email]
    ,[role]
    ,[profile]
    ,[profile_n]
order by [id], [valid_from]
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/44b08/1

Comment: If role differ, getting different output

Comment: It gives NULL to all 3 rows with same profile but different role

Comment: Can you add that input data to the sample in your question so it can be tested?

Comment: The last_modified_date is 'Vendor Team' so it looks like your columns are misaligned

Comment: Can you also add your expected output for sample2?

Comment: Yes , expected output for sample data2 is added

Answer (score 0):

This worked, for different roles as well as correct last_modified_date track

```
with cte as (
    select
        [id]
        ,[email]
        ,[role]
        ,[profile]
        ,[last_modified_date]
        ,case when lag([profile]) over (partition by [id],[email],[role] order by [last_modified_date]) = [profile] then 0 else 1 end as [new_profile]
    from users_table 
),

profile_grouping as (
    select
        [id]
        ,[email]
        ,[role]
        ,[profile]
        ,[last_modified_date]
        ,sum([new_profile]) over ( partition by [id] order by [last_modified_date]) as [profile_n]
    from cte 
),

valid_dates as (
    select
        [id]
        ,[email]
        ,[role]
        ,[profile]
        ,[last_modified_date]
        ,[profile_n]
        ,min(last_modified_date) over (partition by [id], [profile_n] order by [last_modified_date]) as [valid_from]
        ,lead(last_modified_date) over (partition by [id] order by [last_modified_date]) as [valid_to]
    from profile_grouping
)

select
     [id]
    ,[email]
    ,[role]
    ,[profile]
    ,[profile_n]
    ,min([valid_from]) [valid_from]
    ,case when [profile_n] = max([profile_n]) over ( partition by [id] ) then null else max([valid_to]) end [valid_to]
from valid_dates
group by 
     [id]
    ,[email]
    ,[role]
    ,[profile]
    ,[profile_n]
order by [id], [valid_from]
```